# How to choose a real number satisfying these twokinds of inqualities simultaneously?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Real number $\alpha$ is what I want to find to satisfy the following two kinds of inqualities simultaneously for some positive real number $t$
$$\alpha \geq (1-B^2) t+\sqrt 2 B$$
and $$\alpha \geq (1-2 B^2)t+2/t$$
for all $B\in (0,1)$, and $\alpha$ is the smallest positive real number satisfying those conditions.

In other words, $$\alpha = \max_{B\in(0,1)}\max\{(1-B^2) t+\sqrt 2 B,(1-2 B^2)t+2/t\}$$

Comment: Do you want the smallest such $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Yes, I want $\alpha$ to be as small as possible.

Comment: I believe you want $$\alpha=t+\frac2t$$

Comment: @PeterForeman This is correct, in fact the first function is sharply bounded by $\sqrt2$ if $t\le\frac1{\sqrt 2}$ and $t+\frac1{2t}$ otherwise; whereas the second function is sharply bounded by $t+\frac2t$ (Sharp here means that equality occurs for some $B\in[0,1]$)